# Material ui dropdown and other controls doesnt work propertly

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have an issue with the material-ui lib, where the dropdowns and menu doesnt work.

My code is the following.

```
import React from 'react';

import {Toolbar, ToolbarGroup, ToolbarSeparator, ToolbarTitle} from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';


class Interruptions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: 1
      };

      injectTapEventPlugin();
  }
  handleChange(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({value: value});
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div className="interruptions__wrapper">
    <Toolbar>
     <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true}>
       <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} openImmediately={true} onChange={this.handleChange}>
         <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="All Broadcasts" />
         <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="All Voice" />
         <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="All Text" />
         <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Complete Voice" />
         <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Complete Text" />
         <MenuItem value={6} primaryText="Active Voice" />
         <MenuItem value={7} primaryText="Active Text" />
       </DropDownMenu>
     </ToolbarGroup>
     <ToolbarGroup>
       <ToolbarTitle text="Options" />

     </ToolbarGroup>
   </Toolbar>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Interruptions;
```

And this is my main where i render the app in the html.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Interruptions from '../components/Interruptions.jsx';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import {red500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';


const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    textColor: red500,
  }
});

const InterruptionsApp = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
    <Interruptions />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
)


ReactDOM.render(<InterruptionsApp />, document.getElementById('myInterruptions'));
```

Im using openImmediately={true} to see if atleast the menu is showing up (and it does) but when i try to click on it to open it again it doesnt show.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Try moving the "injectTapEventPlugin();" outside your class, right beneath your imports.  That call should occur once at app startup, not in each instantiation of your component(s)

Answer (score 1):

@Jeff McCloud is right. You should injectTapEventPlugin() before you are first use the render function from React-DOM.
I don't know how you build your application webpack or browserify?
I run in this issue too. Be sure that you have declared React, React-DOM, react-tap-event-plugin and all the React addons which you are using to the external libs. I am building a vendor.js for instance.
This approach prevents that you have multiple version of React in your project which could also produce this kind of behavior.

Comment: Im using webpack. The thing is even with some help that i ask in an issue in the site, im still having the problem that i cannot open the dropdown with a mouse click. Do u have any set up for enviroment example to follow? Cuz also i wanna integrate them with arcgis lib. Thanks in advice!

Comment: I had to use the following config on webpack.config.